# r.js build.js deleted all my js folder content

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm in panic.

I'm trying to minify and combine all my js files using `r.js` and after running the `build.js` command it deleted all the content of my js folder... how can I revert it???

I even used the `removeCombined: false`.

I had the problem after this error on the terminal:

`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory` (pointing to a cdn file).

How can I revert it and take back all my files?

Comment: Could you include your config file, so it's very clear what you have done.

Comment: FYI, I removed the `R` tag because `R` is a language (used for math & stats) and is unrelated to "r.js".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is no way to get back your folders or file when you run the r.js build command if it fail for some reason and for no reason it delete your files.

So, in future, for everyone, backup your project or use a repo before running these kind of tasks, I didn't because it was just, fortunately, a mockup.

I found then a good [tutorial](http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project) for doing it and it work fine now (I recovered my files from the browser where there was the project opened yet...).

Comment: `r.js` does not delete files "for no reason." It *will* delete files or clobber your data if you ask it to do something bad.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and there have been [several reports](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/444) of this happening for various reasons, and the author has taken steps to make the API safer to use. I believe some of those features should be better implemented now, so that your source won't be deleted, but you should always be careful and make sure you test your build script in a safe environment.

There is some more information in the [r.js sample config file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js); specifically, check out the comments regarding `allowSourceOverwrites` at the very end of the file.

Comment: Good find! If I followed the plot correctly, versions prior to 2.1.7 were vulnerable to overwriting the source, 2.1.7 is the release that added checks to avoid overwriting the source, and 2.1.11 is the release that added `allowSourceOverwrites` so that the course can be overwritten if the user turns on this flag (which is `false` by default).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to roll it back exactly as it was.

You can `beautify` Javascript, there are lots of plugins for that, but it won't do exactly what you're after.

Comment: There is nothing to beautify. Dropped an error and bye bye all the files. Are crazy the guys that released this r.js???

Comment: It's always worked very well for me. You should include your config.

Comment: how can I include a cdn file?

Comment: That's really a new question